# Rename tag [google-apps] to [google-workspace] and synonymize [gsuite]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Workspace), *Google Workspace* was formerly known as *Google Apps*, and later *G Suite*.

We've been getting some questions tagged [google-workspaces](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspaces), but most of them are tagged [google-apps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps). I just replaced tags on a small handful of questions from [google-workspaces](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspaces) to [google-apps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) with the help of Web Apps moderator Rubén's suggested edits.

So I believe that brings up the question: What name do people most commonly know this service by? To me, `google-apps` feels a bit unspecific since it's an old name that I don't hear too often anymore or associate with the service. The name `gsuite` is instantly recognizable, but it's still a generation behind Google's naming scheme. The name `google-workspace` is what Google is currently calling their product.

I also found a [gsuite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) tag, which has 5 questions attached to it.

To get discussion started, I propose to rename and synonymize the [google-apps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) tag to [google-workspace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace), then synonymize the [gsuite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) tag to [google-workspace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace).

What's the best course of action for these tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plan sounds fine to me.

> rename and synonymize the [google-apps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) tag to [google-workspace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace), then synonymize the [gsuite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) tag to [google-workspace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace).